# How to summarise missing data with data.table/ alternative to tidyverse formulas function?

Tags: r, data.table, anonymous-function

If I want to summarise the missings of multiple columns with `dplyr` I do something like

```r
mtcars %>%
    summarise(across(c(cyl,mpg), ~sum(is.na(.))))
```

How should I do with `data.table`. I understand that the part `summarise + across` should be handle with `lapply + .SDcols` (following https://atrebas.github.io/post/2019-03-03-datatable-dplyr/#select-columns), but I do not know how to introduce a function composition like `~sum(is.na(.))`

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you tag this "lambda-calculus"?

Comment: This is not related to data.table, just check how to reflect "formulas function" (tidyverse-only concept) in base R and then use that function in data.table.

Comment: That is (Thank you for answering jangorecki.). @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I tagged "lambda-calculus" because it is a "formal system for function definition" and is about possible ways of defining/building a function inside data.table that I am asking.

Comment: Not every use of a higher-order function is lambda calculus, and this instance certainly isn't, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table`, specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) with `lapply`, apply the  function to get the summary output

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c('cyl', 'mpg')
as.data.table(mtcars)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x))), .SDcols = nm1]
#    cyl mpg
#1:   0   0
```

The `~` in `tidyverse` syntax is a shorthand lambda syntax for `function(x)`

The tidyverse syntax can be used within `data.table`, but then it will not return a `data.table`

```
as.data.table(mtcars)[, .SD %>%
       summarise(across(c(cyl, mpg), ~ sum(is.na(.))))]
#   cyl mpg
#1   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I am late, but my question should be if there is a shorter alternative to the classical way of defining the anonymous function as you do

Comment: @iago the `~` will not work with data.table as it cannot be evaluated.  It is only for tidyverse

Comment: I know, that's the reason for my question. Is there something equivalent, or a way to compose functions, in `data.table` environment?

Comment: @iago You can still use `tidyverse` within `data.table` if you are okay with that

Comment: @iago there is base R `function` keyword that data.table uses, it does not introduce own API for that. Note that in R 4.1.0 there is going to be shortcut for that in base R.

Comment: @jangorecki and akrun. Thank you!